# How do I refresh my current page

Tags: javascript

i have created 3 to 4 different pages in an html. On navigating to 3rd page; on a particular event, i want to refresh that page. Is it possible? If yes, can you please help me with the code?

Thanks in advance

Cheers

Comment: https://www.google.se/search?q=refresh+the+page+javascript&oq=refresh+the+page+javascript&aqs=chrome.0.69i57j0l3j69i62l2.4026j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Hi Pieter, I guess its not the same with jquery mobile. If I reload in jquery mobile, the complete history gets wiped-off. Can you suggest some other alternative?

Comment: @Praleed: Then explain what you mean by "refresh the page."  Normally that term means to invoke a reload on the page, which would request the original state of the page from the server again (and lose any dynamic client-side changes that haven't persisted server-side).

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can refresh like this `location.reload()`

As you are using jquery mobile and don't want to use `reload` try `changePage` as below:

```
var url = location.href;
if (url.indexOf('?r=1') != -1 || url.indexOf('&r=1') != -1) {
  url = url.replace('?r=1', '?').replace('&r=1', '');
} else {
    if (location.href.indexOf('?') == -1) {
        url = url + '?r=1';
    } else {
        url = url + '&r=1';
    }
}
$.mobile.changePage(url);
```